# Get URL for EcmaScript module after importing in browser

Tags: browser, ecmascript-6, import, module

My start HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="module" src="/way/to/app.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

My `app.js` script is an [EcmaScript Module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules) and loads another EcmaScript Module:

```js
import Mod from "./path/to/module.js";
...
```

this is `module.js`:

```js
// const url = ???

export default class Module {
    constructor() {
        // console.log(url);
    }
}
```

Does exist any method to get loading URL "/way/to/path/to/module.js" in `module.js`? Something like these variables in `nodejs` but for browser:

```js
const dir = __dirname;
const file = __filename;
```

`location.href` gives an URL for start html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome and Firefox both support [`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta):

```
<script type="module">
console.log(import.meta);
</script>
```

In my console that prints:

```
Object { url: "file:///D:/testImportMeta.html" }
```

I think it's not really suited for production, unless Babel supports it. But if you're not over-concerned with lazy browsers, it works well.

It does not work in Node.JS yet.